# SNAT Port Exhaustion - Failed SNAT Connection Detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, azure-appservice

SNAT Port Exhaustion issue comes in ASP.NET Core Web API App which call another API.
An endpoint receive a collection then iterate the collection and call third party API.
The API App is developed in C# Dotnet Core 5.0. It uses HTTP Client to call third party API.
The App also uses Rest client (ReSharper) for some other API call.
Please suggest a solution what code changes would avoid the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Azure App service has limits on connections depending on your plan. I've solved this problem by upgrading to a more robust plan, that allowed me more connections. Another optimization I did was keep connection open when making multiple calls to same APi.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to optimize the code to overcome the problem. upgrading the plan and scaling out is the last option.  In my scenario, An API will call 3rd party API. There are many call to API that could cause issue. I cannot keep the connection open indefinitely right. I did the code optimization as Microsoft suggestion.  I tried Type client Approach and similar Named Client Approach. both did not work if do load test continuously.  is it possible to reuse the pool irrespective of no request over the period of time in Basic tier.May I know the right value for "SetHandlerLifetime"

Comment: Unfortunately if your application makes numerous connections to external services, you will need to scale up to a more expensive plan, where you can make more simultaneous connections. There's no free lunch. Take a look at [this](https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/)

Comment: Can you please lookinto my code and suggest if I need to improve the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758626/asp-net-core-5-0-web-api-deployed-in-app-service-call-third-party-api-fails-inte

Comment: how many API calls are you doing in order to make SNAT exhausted? ?

Comment: The optimization I would do after I saw your code is share a singleton HttpClient [see](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core)

Comment: I need to know metrics for each plan and then we can think of scale out.

Comment: today, I ran 2500  postman collection each iteration it call 3 time same API. so totally 7500. I got 18 failure. May I know which metric can I watch to see no of SNAT port used and average

Comment: You can find all relevant information in [oficial docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors)

Comment: Each App Service instance has 128 ports (tcp connections) available.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, we know [the SNAT ports is a limited resource of a stamp](https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/#snat-ports-exhaustion). This article does a really good job of explaining how SNAT works and some details about the limits. You also can read the content of [How to solve a SNAT port exhaustion issue for App Service](https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/#how-to-solve-a-snat-port-exhaustion-issue-for-app-service).

In this offical blog, you will learn more about [Reducing SNAT Port consumption in Azure App Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/reducing-snat-port-consumption-in-azure-app-services/).

Comment: I tried optimize the code as per Microsoft but that doesn't work. The service plan is basic and we want code not to fail irrespective of load ie no of request. How can I set the httpclient to use the pool and to avoid this issue. what is the right setting for    "SetHandlerLifetime". This is my startup code.                   services.AddHttpClient<IGeoBusRestService, GeoBusRestServiceOne>()
            .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))  //Set lifetime to five minutes
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());

Comment: Can you please look into my code and suggest if I need to improve the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758626/asp-net-core-5-0-web-api-deployed-in-app-service-call-third-party-api-fails-inte